# Protect emails from deletion in Gmail

Tags: gmail, account-management, passwords

In our company, we always create a common email address to put things to check by project common people. Maybe some important emails can be delete recklessly. So I feel some or all mails can be protected, so no one can delete those. These mails can be password protected and the password can be different and only known to account creator or admin.

Is there any possibility to find the solution for this within Gmail or Labs?

Comment: They need to be be trained to never delete in gmail. Always label, and archive.

Comment: I have edited your question a bit so that it remains within the scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that exists.

**Alternative:** You should have a separate email address for those "users with limited rights". Forward automatically all incoming emails to that second address and let those users access only that address. Then, they can then delete any emails they want, that won't affect the main email inbox. This is extremely easy to setup in Gmail and prevents any accidental deletion.